# How to prefer local network with remote domain name?

Tags: networking, router, nas

I have a NAS working under my LAN network. Let's say 192.168.1.5
I have a custom domain name such as mynas.com linked to my fixed IP address , routed to this IP.

Now, I want to setup my devices (iPhones, etc.) to my NAS using one and single URL/IP.

Normally I would enter my custom domain name. But when I'm at home, I don't want my traffic to go through internet when it's available under the LAN network.

How can I setup a system which routes my traffic only in local when I'm at home, and by internet when I'm away?

Thank you,

Answer (score 1):

If your router supports it, you could configure DNS entries on the router that map to the local IP address.

I've done this in DD-WRT by configuring the `addn-hosts` option under the DNSMasq settings.

[image: DD-WRT Services Screenshot]

The `/jffs/etc/config/dns.txt` file it references contains entries like:

> 192.168.1.1 router
>   192.168.1.2 switch
>   192.168.1.3 nas

Which would be expanded to `router.domain.com`, `switch.domain.com`, and `nas.domain.com` and then mapped to your local IP address(es) when you're on your local network using your router's DNS.  This means the initial DNS query goes to your router, but all traffic after that is strictly between your client and server without going through the router.

When you're away from home the internet DNS servers would resolve `nas.domain.com` to your public IP address.

Answer (score 0):

I think you do not have to do anything at all, you can use your public IP/domain from inside your home network too.

Your router will see that the packet is destined for itself and via the port forward you probably already have the packets get routed to the NAS (while staying in your network all the time).

**Edit**: the only disadvantage of this vs. using 192.168.1.5 is that the packets always go through the gateway (i.e. your router).

Comment: This confirms what I suspected without being sure. I'll have a look at the in/out stats of my router to be sure. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Sidenote: If the user is using NAT (very likely) then the router will need to understand hairpin-NAT.  If it does not then this will not work.